# Filtrar datos C# Visual studio2017 con linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017

buenas necesito ayuda para filtrar la información mostrada en un datagrid segun el id de un estado civil (combobox), el problema es que al depurar el método para revisarlo, la consulta a la base de datos solo esta realizando el Select, pero no el "Where" para discriminar los datos.

```
public List<Cliente> ReadAllByEstadoCivil()
    {

        BeLifeDatos.BeLifeEntities bbdd = new BeLifeDatos.BeLifeEntities();

        try
        {
            List<BeLifeDatos.Cliente> listaDatos = bbdd.Cliente.ToList<BeLifeDatos.Cliente>();

            List<Cliente> listaNegocio = GenerarListaFiltroEstadoCivil(listaDatos);

            return listaNegocio.Where(c => c.IdEstadoCivil == IdEstadoCivil).ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<Cliente>();
        }
    }

    public List<Cliente> GenerarListaFiltroEstadoCivil(List<BeLifeDatos.Cliente> listaDatosCliente)
    {
        List<Cliente> listaCliente = new List<Cliente>();

        foreach (BeLifeDatos.Cliente dato in listaDatosCliente)
        {
            Cliente c = new Cliente();

            CommonBC.Syncronize(dato, c);

            listaCliente.Add(c);
        }


        return listaCliente;
    }
```

Comment: probaste hacer el linq y recorrer esa lista con un foreach?

Answer (score 0):

- Está claro que la consulta a la base no hace ningún filtro:

  ```
  List<BeLifeDatos.Cliente> listaDatos = bbdd.Cliente.ToList<BeLifeDatos.Cliente>();
  ```

Si quieres aplicar el filtro en la consulta a la base deberías aplicarlo allí:

```
List<BeLifeDatos.Cliente> listaDatos = bbdd.Cliente.Where(c => c.IdEstadoCivil == IdEstadoCivil).ToList<BeLifeDatos.Cliente>();
```

- Tu aplicas el filtro luego de transformar la lista de entidades.
- No queda claro de donde sale la variable IdEstadoCivil que usas para dicho filtro.

Answer (score 0):

No veo donde este asignado el filtro, pero vamos a suponer que tu se lo vas a enviar al metodo para filtrar. en una linea con el uso de Where puedes regresar solo los registros que cumplan ese requisito.

```
public List<Cliente> Filtrar(List<BeLifeDatos.Cliente> listaDatosCliente, filtro)
{
  return listaDatosCliente.Where(x => x.IdEstadoCivil == filtro).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me dijeron donde estaba el problema me faltaba agregar estas 2 lineas en el evento del botón de filtrar, ya que no le estaba asignando un valor al IDestadocivil, les agradezco de todas formas sus respuestas :)

```
Cliente c = new Cliente();
c.IdEstadoCivil = (int)cbestadocivil2.SelectedValue;
```